# (Java) Drawn Rectangles do not appear

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

So am working on a School Project, and I want to draw a game board made out of Rectangles which are saved in an array. I managed to do that, but only the last drawn Rectangle Stays on the Panel. I'm really desperate and i don't know where my mistake is.

The Field is a 4x5 field. The Coordinates saved in the Tile Class:

the first two represent the upper left Corner

the last two represent the bottom right corner of it

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class quoVadis{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
} 

class Tile {
    Random rGen = new Random();
    int sX,sY,eX,eY;
    Color farbe;
    public Tile(int sX, int sY,int eX,int eY){
        this.sX = sX;
        this.sY = sY;
        this.eX = eX;
        this.eY = eY;
        farbe = new Color(rGen.nextInt(156)+100,rGen.nextInt(156)+100,rGen.nextInt(156)+100);
    }
}

class Frame extends JFrame{

    private Game game;
        final int GAMESIZE = 400;
        final int PANELSIZE = GAMESIZE/5;
    public Frame() { 

        super("Quo Vadis");     
        this.setSize(GAMESIZE, GAMESIZE*5/4);
        this.setLocation(50, 50);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        game = new Game(GAMESIZE, PANELSIZE);
        game.setLayout(null);
        game.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.getContentPane().add(game);


        this.setVisible(true);
   }

    }
class Game extends JPanel{
    int GAMESIZE;
    int PANELSIZE;
    private Tile field[][]=new Tile[4][5]; 
    Random rGen = new Random(4711);
    Tile stein;

    public Game(int g, int p) {
        GAMESIZE = g;
        PANELSIZE = p;
```

// The Mistake has to be in this following Part:

```
        int idx=0;  
        for(Tile i:levels){
            for(int j = i.sX; j <= i.eX; j++){
                for(int k = i.sY; k <= i.eY; k++){
                    field[j][k] = levels[idx];
                }
            }
            idx++;
         }

            for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
                for(int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
                    if(field[j][k]==null)continue;
                    stein=field[j][k];
                    draw((field[j][k].sX * PANELSIZE) , (field[j][k].sY * PANELSIZE) , ((((field[j][k].eX-field[j][k].sX) + 1) * PANELSIZE) -1),  ((((field[j][k].eY-field[j][k].sY)+ 1) * PANELSIZE) -1));
                }

            }

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    int rx, ry,rdx,rdy;
    private void draw(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        rx=a;
        ry=b;
        rdx=c;
        rdy=d;
        repaint(rx,ry,rdx,rdy);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(stein.farbe);
      g.fillRect(rx, ry, rdx, rdy);
   }
    Tile[] levels = {
        new Tile(1,0,2,1),
        new Tile(0,0,0,1),
        new Tile(3,0,3,1),
        new Tile(0,2,0,3),
        new Tile(1,2,2,2),
        new Tile(3,2,3,3),
        new Tile(0,4,0,4),
        new Tile(1,3,1,3),
        new Tile(2,3,2,3),
        new Tile(3,4,3,4),
        };
}
```

I already checked the Position of the Rectangles in numbers and they are correct in every way so they do not overlap or something like that.

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my primary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw each rectangle inside of your `paintComponent` method every time.

Currently you are calling your draw method for one rectangle then you call repaint and draw that single rectangle. `paintComponent` will redraw the entire panel each time it is called. This means that it will on preserve the last rectangle (the rest were "repainted over".

You want to loop through all of your tiles and use the drawRect method to draw them inside of your `paintComponent` method so they will be drawn every time.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g)

      for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
                if(field[j][k]==null)continue;
                stein=field[j][k];
                 g.setColor(stein.farbe);
                g.fillRect((field[j][k].sX * PANELSIZE) , (field[j][k].sY * PANELSIZE) , ((((field[j][k].eX-field[j][k].sX) + 1) * PANELSIZE) -1),  ((((field[j][k].eY-field[j][k].sY)+ 1) * PANELSIZE) -1));
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: how do i save all the single, differently colored rectangles and draw them all at once?

Comment: see my update, it should give you a better idea but is untested.

Comment: yay its drawing all of them now ^_^ Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have one more question. Why does it work now? i mean, repaint or something like that is not being called anywhere, and how can i update the board, if i change the location of something?

Comment: The paintComponent method is called by default when rendering a JPanel (or any component). Now if you update the board you can call repaint in order to redraw it.

Comment: hmm somehow when i call repaint(); it does not do anything, no matter when or where i cast it. do i have to give it some special arguments?

Comment: Are you changing anything when you call repaint()?

Comment: I changed the position of the Tiles in the array, and then i tried to repaint it.

Comment: yet it doesnt do anything

Comment: Where do you change your tiles are you using an event to trigger this?

Comment: yes the change is triggered by a mouseevent. shall i ask a new question and post the code?

Comment: I think i found my problem. When i Changed the position of the tiles i only changed the entry in the array, but the repaint method takes the position of the tiles not from the array but the tiles itself, and the information in the tiles remained unchanged

Comment: Ah nice, glad you figured it out!